# How to filter products in linq to entities and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, filtering, linq-to-entities

I have a table that maps `Products` to `Specs` and `SpecOptions` and `SpecUnits`:

`MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec` table:

```
public class MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ProductId {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int SpecId {get; set;}

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SpecOptionId {get; set;}

    public int? SpecUniId {get; set;}
}
```

`Spec`:

```
public class Spec 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<SpecOption> Options {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec> Maps {get; set;}
}
```

SpecOption:

```
public class SpecOption 
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual Spec Spec {get; set;}
    public int SpecId {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec> Maps {get; set;}
}
```

I get `SpecId`, `SpecOptionId` and `SpecUnitId` from user, it should be noted that `SpecUnitId` might be NULL.

I need to get those `Products` that have all my criteria at the same time, not just one of them.

In other words, it must be an `AND` between Specs and `OR` between SpecOptions of a Spec.

Example:

```
SpecId    SpecOptionId    SpecUnit
----------------------------------
15        24              NULL
6         71              6
7         72              2
```

How I'm doing it now:

```
var maps = _db.MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec.AsQueryable();
var specPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec>();

foreach (var gp in model.GroupBy(x => x.SpecId)) 
{
    var optionPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec>();

    foreach (var map in gp) 
    {
        optionPredicate = optionPredicate.Or(y => y.SpecOptionId == y.OptionId && map.UnitId == map.UnitId);
    }

    specPredicate = specPredicate.And(optionPredicate);
}

var query = maps.AsExpandable().Where(specPredicate).Select(x => x.Product);
```

Although I have products with those criteria, I get nothing when I execute my query.

How can I achieve this?

**Note:** I'm using [Albahari's PredicateBuilder](https://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: @jarlh - No I need to go with entity framework linq to entities.

Comment: Shouldin't `map.UnitId == map.UnitId` be `y.UnitId == map.UnitId` ?

Comment: @StevePy - You’re right, but it was a typo, it doesn’t make any change. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out (using [Albahari's PredicateBuilder](https://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)):

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Product>();

foreach (var filterGp in filters.GroupBy(x => x.SpecId)) {
    var innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Product>();

    foreach (var filter in filterGp) {
        innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(x => x.MapProductSpecOptionSpecUnitSpec.Any(y => y.SpecOptionId == filter.OptionId && y.SpecUnitId == filter.UnitId));
    }

    predicate = predicate.And(innerPredicate);
}

query = query.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
```